# Getting an error while FTP file using FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am getting following exception while ftp file over to some other machine.

```
org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:151)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:373)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1360)
    at com.fs.ftp.FTPUsingFTPClientApache.startFTP(FTPUsingFTPClientApache.java:40)
    at com.fs.ftp.FTPUsingFTPClientApache.main(FTPUsingFTPClientApache.java:17)
```

The Code that i am using for FTP is something like :-

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect("home.abc.com");
ftpClient.login("remote", "guesst12");
int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
    System.out.println("Connection proper");
}

if(ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("share")) {
    System.out.println("Directory Change Succesfull");
}
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("H:/testFile.txt"));
BufferedInputStream inputStrean = new BufferedInputStream(input);
if(ftpClient.storeFile("testFile.txt", input)) {
    System.out.println("File Stored Successfully");
}
input.close();
inputStrean.close();
ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

The above exception i get at line `ftpClient.storeFile("testFile.txt", input)`.

Am i missing something, or using it not the correct way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch that exception, call its `getIOException()` method to get the exception that caused the problem, an print its stacktrace.  That will tell you what `IOException` caused the copy to fail.

Comment: I added one of the line in the code `ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` after this the code executes properly, but at the remote machine, file of 0KB is created with no content. Will this help..

Comment: @M.J. - Not really.  You've changed the problem rather than working out what the original one was.  What would help more is the information I suggested that you look at / provide.

Answer (score 2):

I want to support above solution, however I don't have enough reputation yet.
That save me finally!

```
        ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftps.execPBSZ(0) ;
        ftps.execPROT("P") ;
```

By the way, my issue is "connection is reset during process of transfer". Below 2 commands are the key commands to me.
            ftps.execPBSZ(0) ;
            ftps.execPROT("P") ;

Answer (score 1):

For my experience, this error was caused because the filesystem was full

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with file 0KB (example PDF files) once tranfered by ftps you have to force Passive Mode and set File Type

```
            ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftps.execPBSZ(0) ;
            ftps.execPROT("P") ;
```